# Не хочет запускаться сервер Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Запускаю rails server, выдает следующее.
Уже не знаю, что делать

[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, отправляйте ошибки текстом, а не скриншотом. Очень неудобно текст копипастить с картинки

Answer (score 1):

Поддержка руби от версии 2.7 и выше начинается с 6-х рельс. Так что или ниже версию руби ставить, или выше - версию рельс